# Using EPPlus from Excel to DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, epplus

Currently i am trying to read in data from excel to DataTable in C# using EPPlus.

The main problem i am currently facing is the empty column in excel is not being pick up when i am populating the headers for DataTable and because of that, when i try to load in the data into my DataTable, the columns get screwed up (data being read into the wrong column).

Is there a way to maybe map the column name in DataTable with the Excel worksheet column name so they woul dpopulate correctly?

Excel Data

```
| Column 1  |  Column 2   |      | Column 3 |
|   Value   |    Value    |      |   123    |
|  Value 2  |   Value 2   |      |   234    |
```

In my codes, I create all the headers in DataTable from Excel

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
ExcelWorksheet ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[worksheetName];

foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[rowStart, 1, rowStart, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
{
    int num = 1;
    string header = firstRowCell.Text;

    Common.writeLog("header - " + firstRowCell);

    if (header.Contains("\n"))
    {
       header = header.Replace("\n", " ");
    }

    while (dt.Columns.Contains(header))
    {
       header = firstRowCell.Text + num;
       num++;

       if (header.Contains("\n"))
       {
           header = header.Replace("\n", " ");
       }
    }

    //Common.writeLog("header - " + header);
    dt.Columns.Add(header);

}
```

DataTable Header

```
Column 1 , Column 2 , Column 3
```

Next, I will read in the Excel data into my DataTable

```
 int startRow = rowStart + 1;
 for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
 {
     var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
     var row = dt.NewRow();
     foreach (var cell in wsRow)
     {
         try
         {
             row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Value;
         }
         catch (Exception) { }
     }
     dt.Rows.Add(row);
 }
```

Current Data in DataTable

```
| Column 1  |  Column 2   | Column 3 |
|   Value   |    Value    |          |
|  Value 2  |   Value 2   |          |
```